# Fastest way to generate all binary strings of size n into a boolean array?

Tags: java, binary, boolean

For example, if I wanted all binary strings of length 3 I could simply declare them like this:

```
boolean[] str1 = {0,0,0};
boolean[] str2 = {0,0,1};
boolean[] str3 = {0,1,0};
boolean[] str4 = {0,1,1};
boolean[] str5 = {1,0,0};
boolean[] str6 = {1,0,1};
boolean[] str7 = {1,1,0};
boolean[] str8 = {1,1,1};
```

What is the most efficient way to generate all possibly binary strings of length N into a **boolean array**?

I don't necessarily need *the* most efficient method, just one that's fairly efficient and easy for me to multithread.

EDIT: I should note that I will be storing them all in an ArrayList, if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some code to generate a truth table... (works for only for 32 bits because of array size limits ( you can change the size variable to whatever and store booleans as 1/0 if you want):

```
int size = 3;
    int numRows = (int)Math.pow(2, size);
    boolean[][] bools = new boolean[numRows][size];
    for(int i = 0;i<bools.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < bools[i].length; j++)
        {
            int val = bools.length * j + i;
            int ret = (1 & (val >>> j));
            bools[i][j] = ret != 0;
            System.out.print(bools[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: I'm liking this method. I'll wait for some more though.

Comment: @chickeneaterguy: Since you said that you want to multithread it, one (or two) trivial improvement(s) I'd make here are: 1) Move the prints out of the loops, and 2) change the type of i to an AtomicInteger (making necessary adjustments). #2 could then be adapted trivially to a multithreaded implementation.  Not sure how much you'll gain this way, as the code block here is tiny.  A better way of dividing the work on threads might be to split the ranges on i for each thread.

Comment: @user314104 : I did it. It's fast. I did it with an arraylist instead but I used your method. Thanks!

Comment: Only it will fail at n=31

Answer (score 4):

Example: If you need of length 4, then you must have 2^4 = 16 different arrays.

You can use this simple Java code to generate all arrays:

```
for (int i=0; i < (Math.pow(2,4)); i++) {
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
}
```

The output of this:

> 0 1 10 11 100 101 110 111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111

Answer (score 3):

If you do not care about having all the permutations at once, a smart thing to do is to **allocate no memory beforehand** and simply write an algorithm which **calculates** the `strX` you want, on-the-fly.

Advantages of doing this:

- You can handle **arbitrarily large number** of permutations without having to allocate all permutations
- Since the algorithm stores nothing, it is **thread friendly**
- You only pay for the rows that you want.  For example, if n=1,000, but you only need a few of the permutations, this will be **much faster and require a tiny fraction of memory (only one row worth)**

To get you started, the algorithm's interface can look something like this:

> boolean[] getRow( int rowNumber, int nItems )

So you would call `getRow(5,3)` to get `str5` returned from the function.  I leave it up to you to implement the details (it's not hard).

Answer (score 1):

Implemented it in a function-

```
static public ArrayList<boolean[]> getBoolArr(int length) {
        int numOptions = 1 << length;
        ArrayList<boolean[]> finalArray = new ArrayList<boolean[]>();
        for(int o=0;o<numOptions;o++) {
            boolean[] newArr = new boolean[length];
            for(int l=0;l<length;l++) {
                int val = ( 1<<l ) & o;
                newArr[l] = val>0;
            }
            finalArray.add(newArr);
        }
        return finalArray;
    }
```

example of usage-

```
ArrayList<boolean[]> res = getBoolArr(2); //2 is your length, change it however you want.
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. If I use low numbers as length I get out of bounds exceptions. If I use large numbers I get 1-digit outputs. I don't understand all of the << and whatnot. Care to explain?

Comment: try again, it works. I've put the code inside a function so there is no place for mistakes (see update). let me know if you have any problems. '<<' and '&' are bit operators. see http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/expressions/bitops.html for explanation (it's c++ but works for java too).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in Java

```
public class NbitsStrings {
    int[] arrA;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Input the Number Of bits you want.
        int n = input.nextInt();
        NbitsStrings i = new NbitsStrings(n);
        i.nBits(n);
    }
    public NbitsStrings(int n) {
        arrA = new int[n];
    }
    public void nBits(int n) {
        if (n <= 0) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int value : arrA) {
                builder.append(value);
            }
            String text = builder.toString();
            System.out.println(text);
        } else {
            arrA[n - 1] = 0;
            nBits(n - 1);
            arrA[n - 1] = 1;
            nBits(n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`javascript` implementation relevant to duplicate Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591231/calculate-all-possible-combinations-of-n-off-on-elements.

As with all numbers, there is a relationship between sets of numbers, where once the pattern is recognized, addition can be used to derive the relationships between sets of numbers at specific indexes within an array sets.

```js
let [N, n1, n2, n3] = [0, 1, 9, 89];

let [res, max] = [Array(Array(3).fill(N)), Math.pow(2, 3)];

for (let i = 1, curr; i < max; i++) {

  if ([1, 3, 5, 7].some(n => n === i)) {
    N += n1;
  }

  if ([2, 6].some(n => n === i)) {
    N += n2;
  }

  if (i === max / 2) {
    N += n3;
  }

  curr = Array.from(String(N), n => +n);

  if (N < 100) {
    while (curr.length < 3) {
      curr.unshift(n1 - 1);
    }
  }

  res.push(curr);

}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I implemented it in Scala**

```
def combinations(n: Int): List[List[Int]] = {
 val numbers = scala.math.pow(2, n).toInt 
 //Convert each to binary equivalent 
 def toBinary(decimal: Int, binary: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  if (decimal <= 0)
    return le(binary)
  toBinary(decimal / 2, (decimal % 2) :: binary)
 }
 // Size alignment 
 def le(binary: List[Int]):List[Int]=
  {
    if(binary.length!=n) le(0::binary) else binary
  }
 def getCombinations(n: Int, list: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = {
  if (n < 0)
    return list
  getCombinations(n - 1, toBinary(n, Nil) :: list)
 }
 getCombinations(numbers - 1, Nil)
}
```

**Sample output:**

- combinations(2) //List(List(0, 0), List(0, 1), List(1, 0), List(1, 1))
- combinations(3) //List(List(0, 0, 0), List(0, 0, 1), List(0, 1, 0), List(0, 1, 1), List(1, 0, 0), List(1, 0, 1), List(1, 1, 0), List(1, 1, 1))

**Thanks to my friend James A.**