# Algorithm for finding string permutations where each position varies

Tags: string, permutation

Let's say I have a three character string "ABC". I want to generate all permutations of that string where a single letter can be replaced with his lower-case equivalent. For example, "aBC", "abC", "abc", "AbC", "Abc", etc. In other words, given a regexp like [Aa][Bb][Cc] generate every string that can be matched by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be trivially reduced to generating all binary sequences of length `n`. This has been previously addressed, for example in [Fastest way to generate all binary strings of size n into a boolean array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374079/fastest-way-to-generate-all-binary-strings-of-size-n-into-a-boolean-array) and [all permutations of a binary sequence x bits long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928297/all-permutations-of-a-binary-sequence-x-bits-long).

Comment: Not exactly, you can use either "A" or "a" - not both (in the same permutation item)

Comment: @alfasin: Not sure I follow. Each binary digit corresponds to a letter. `0` is lowercase, `1` is uppercase. `000` stands for `abc`, `001` for `abC`, `010` for `aBc` and so on.

Comment: if you use lowercase "a" you MUST use the capitals: "B" and "C" in this same permutation. At least according to his definition: "where a single letter can be replaced..."

Comment: @alfasin: That's what he says, but I doubt he means it. Look at the examples: they repeatedly violate the constraint.

Comment: I am using upper-/lower-case only as an example: the transformation on the character is table-driven.

Comment: @NPE I guess you're right - the problem is not defined very well. +1

Comment: @NPE is correct, the issue is that each character in the string can have multiple variants, and I want to generate the set of all combinations of strings with the variants in the same position.

Comment: Think of it this way: I have a set of strings that can be described the regexp [Aa][Bb][Cc] and I want to generate all strings that can be generated with that regexp.